# No puedo crear base de datos porque dice que estoy sin privilegios en phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql

Buen día. Necesito dar privilegios a un usuario donde la base de datos está en un servidor no en mi pc, por lo que no tengo el control total y al querer crear una base de datos nueva me sale

> Error 1044. Access denied for user 'bn_m'@'190.55.xx.xxx' (using password: YES)

Ese es el único usuario que esta asignado a esa base de datos.

Intenté con esta consulta.

```
mysql>GRANT SUPER ON . TO 'bn_m@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'contraseña';
mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Pero me sale el error:

> 1045 Access denied for user 'bn_m'@'190.55.xx.xxx' (using password: YES)

Que no tengo privilegios.

Alguien me pueda ayudar, gracias.

Comment: Mencionas que la base de datos esta en un servidor y no en tu pc, entonces considero que en la consulta de otorgar privilegios esta mal que pongas esto `localhost`

Answer (score 0):

Estas intentando acceder a un servidor **remoto** (`190.55.xx.xxx`), pero los permisos los estas concediendo a `localhost`, es decir, a **conexiones provenientes desde la misma `IP`**.

### Solución

- Si deseas poder ingresar desde **una computadora específica**, entonces debes reemplazar `localhost` por la [`IP Pública`](https://whatismyipaddress.com/) de dicha máquina.

  ```
   GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'bn_m'@'[IP_PUBLICA]' IDENTIFIED BY 'contraseña';
  ```
- Si deseas poder ingresar desde **cualquier computadora**, entonces debes reemplazar `localhost` por `%`.

  ```
   GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'bn_m'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'contraseña';
  ```

Comment: gracias por responder lo he intentado de las dos formas y nada.  no lo estoy haciendo por el xampp si no por bitnami que me da una  base de datos pero necesito importar una mi base de datos que es donde tengo la información que necesito pero no me deja por falta de privilegios no se si hay alguna manera de poder hacerlo o otra forma de poder traer mis datos